# ¿What is actually the Working directory in Git?

Tags: java, git

I am spending lots of time to get a clear idea about the 'Working directory in Git'
Is it a especific folder or directory? or is a version of a directory? Can anyone help me to understand this concept.
What if I create a directory 'mydir' locally
then I run: git init.
thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between working directory and local repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692155/whats-the-difference-between-working-directory-and-local-repository)

Answer (score 4):

In Git, the phrase *working directory* **was** once a synonym for *working tree*.  It isn't any longer, because the phrase *working directory* may also be used by your OS (usually with a third word in front, as *current working directory*).  Modern Git tries to use the phrase *working tree* as much as possible, though this is sometimes shortened to *work-tree* or *worktree*, as in `git worktree add` for instance.

In your OS, when they use the phrase *current working directory*, this refers to the folder or directory<sup>1</sup> you are working in at the time.  That may be within your *working tree*.

In Git, the phrase *working tree* refers to the OS-maintained directories-and-files that hold *your* copies of files.  These are **yours**, to deal with as you wish: Git simply *fills them in* from committed files.

> What if I create a directory 'mydir' locally then I [run]: `git init`

Let me rephrase this as the following series of shell commands:

```
$ mkdir mydir
$ cd mydir
$ git init
```

The `mkdir` creates a new, empty directory, within your current working directory.  The `cd` then enters this empty directory, so that now what was `./mydir` is your current working directory.  The `git init` command runs with its own current working directory being this empty directory.

Since the directory `mydir` was empty at the time you ran `git init`, Git will create a hidden directory / folder named `.git` within this `mydir` directory.  This hidden directory contains the *repository proper*.  The repository consists of a number of files and directories that implement several databases:

- One database is a simple [key-value store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database) that uses *hash IDs* to locate internal Git *objects*.  This is the main (and usually largest) of the two primary databases that make up a Git repository.
- One database is another simple key-value store that uses names as keys, to store hash IDs, which are then used in the first database.  This is the secondary database that makes up a Git repository.  This particular database's implementation in current versions of Git tends to be a bit dodgy: it relies too much on your operating system.  On macOS and Windows, it tends to be a bit flawed.  There is ongoing work in Git to replace this with a proper database implementation, which will eliminate this problem.
- Apart from these two main databases, the repository contains many auxiliary files, including Git's *index* (aka *staging area*).  The most important point here is that all of these entities live within the `.git` directory, though.

As there are no *commits* yet, both main databases are empty.  At this point, so is Git's index.

Your *work-tree* consists of all files and directories inside your current working directory *except* the `.git` directory, which holds Git's files.  Since your work-tree is yours, and is maintained by your OS (not by Git), you can now create any files you like here.

At some point, you will want to have Git create a new commit.  This will be the very first commit in the repository.  To create this commit, you will add the files you would like to go into this initial commit, into Git's index / staging-area, using `git add`.  The `git add` program works by copying your work-tree files into Git's index.  So, with your OS's *current working directory* being the `mydir` directory, you can now just create some file(s):

```
$ echo "repository for project X" > README
$ git add README
$ git commit
```

The `echo` command here creates a new file named `README` in your *working tree*.  The `git add` command takes the working tree file, compresses and Git-ifies it to make it ready to be stored in a new commit, and writes the stored file into Git's index.<sup>2</sup>  The final command, `git commit`, gathers some metadata from you—the person making the commit—and writes out Git's index and this metadata, storing the results in the main database, to create a new commit.

Once you've made this new, initial commit—the very first commit in the repository—it becomes possible for branch names to exist.  They cannot exist until this point because each branch name *must* hold a *valid, existing hash ID*, and hash IDs for future commits are not predictable.<sup>3</sup>  Now that there is *one* commit, that's the only hash ID that any branch name can hold.<sup>4</sup>

Over time, you will add more and more commits to the repository.  (In general, it's pretty rare to ever *drop* a commit, except for, e.g., the way `git rebase` replaces commits with new-and-improved ones.  It's not impossible, it is just difficult.)  Each new commit therefore *adds to* the repository.

The repository itself, then, consists of:

- the databases that hold commits and other objects, and the names that find them;
- Git's index, used to hold your proposed next commit; and
- other maintenance items that you and/or Git may find useful.

The commit objects, and in fact all objects in the big database, are strictly read-only.  Nothing and no one can ever change them.  They're in a form that is directly useful only to Git itself, though.

Cloning the repository consists of copying the two databases, although the *names* database is only partly copied, and gets changed during the cloning process.

Meanwhile, your *working tree* is where you have Git *extract* commits, turning stuff that's only directly useful to *Git*—and that is read-only—into stuff you can *work with* and modify.  These are *your* files.  This is how you do your work, in your working tree.  You can use the results to update Git's index, and then use Git's index to create a *new* commit, that adds on to the repository without changing anything that already exists *in* the repository.

---

<sup>1</sup>At the OS level, the terms *folder* and *directory* are synonyms.  Git itself does not *store* folders or directories: it just stores files whose names may contain embedded slashes, such as `path/to/file.ext`.  That's all one single file name.  Your *OS* may force you to first make a folder named `path`, then in that folder, make a folder named `to`, and only then use the combined `path` and `to` folders to make a file named `file.ext` within that path.  The *current working directory* can be changed to `path`, so that you would use the name `to/file.ext`, instead of `path/to/file.ext`, or even to `path/to` so that you would use the name `file.ext`.  In all cases, Git will *internally* work with a *stored* file named `path/to/file.ext`.  So your *current working directory* is an OS concept, referring to how you move around within the folders that your OS maintains.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, the index doesn't actually hold the *files* directly.  It holds instead a Git *blob object* hash ID for the file, which provides the key to the key-value object database so that Git can look up the file's content, plus the *name* of the file—complete with (forward) slashes—and some additional information.  The blob object holds a compressed and de-duplicated copy of the file's content.

This de-duplication, and the fact that it is `git add` that readies the file for committing, means that `git commit` will go quite fast, as it need not prepare anything for committing: it just saves, permanently, the blob objects already stored in the index.

<sup>3</sup>The hash ID of a commit is a cryptographic checksum of the commit's complete content.  The content include not only the saved source files (as an internal Git *tree* object), but also the exact date-and-time-stamp.  Since we don't even know what you'll commit in the future, much less exactly *when* you will commit it, we cannot compute what the future hash ID will be.  You may know *what* you will commit, which gets you closer; but unless you know exactly *when* you will commit it, you won't know the hash ID either.

<sup>4</sup>Branch names in particular are constrained: they may only hold a commit hash ID.  Tag names can hold the hash ID of any of Git's four internal object types.  (Usually, though, a tag name either holds a commit hash ID, or the hash ID of a newly-created *annotated tag object*, which in turn holds a commit hash ID.)  Other types of names may have their own constraints.

Comment: Thanks for your help  torek. It is clear for me now.